# How to reference Microsoft.BizTalk.CAT.Samples.DynamicTransforms.Helpers.Properties;

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm looking at sample code here: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2010/01/29/how-to-boost-message-transformations-using-the-xslcompiledtransform-class/

But I can't get the helper routine to compile because this statement:

> using
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.CAT.Samples.DynamicTransforms.Helpers.Properties;

is giving error:

> The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.BizTalk.CAT.Samples.DynamicTransforms.Helpers'
>   (are you missing an assembly reference?)

If I comment that line out, then I get errors on the class "customBTXMessage" (the type or namespace ... cannot be found...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sample is for BizTalk 2010.

You should not need to do that for BizTalk 2013 and up, as it already uses XSLT Compiled transform.
This actually caused a few problems as per [Known issues in BizTalk Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2954101/known-issues-in-biztalk-server-2013)

To run lots of map for testing purposes I would use [BizUnit](https://github.com/BizUnit/BizUnit)

Comment: In order to do some mass testing (converting 100s of maps from 2010 to 2013), I'm trying to call a map from C#; might have found another way to do it.

Comment: @NealWalters Ok, are you going to write about how you did it?  We usually use BizUnit and create tests to run all the maps

Comment: I might.  I've seen BizUnit, but never done much with it.  Can it run the maps without creating the receive/send ports?

Comment: @NealWalters Yes, it runs in Visual Studio rather than in BIzTalk.

Comment: Any idea what mapspec would be in this code fragment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a4dd41f-9d3e-4355-94ff-3b663a0c186c/possible-to-call-biztalk-map-in-c-coding?forum=biztalkgeneral.  I have some Powershell scripts already written, and I'm thinking about changing them to call the map, via a C# Helper class.

Comment: it looks like it wants an XSLT text file, I thought it was the btm map DLL at first, kind of like a DocSpec.

Comment: MapSpec = BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bt_MapSpec   Basically they mean the TypeName of the map.  When maps are compiled they are XSLT

Comment: I know this is a question for Greg there, which I did ask.  I got it to work by doing test map, saving the .xslt, and passing the filename of the XSLT.  I'll see if there are alternatives to load .dll instead.

Comment: @NealWalters Yes, you can load it from the compiled assembly, it's just a string property you can get by Reflection, sorry don't remember exactly what is called.  But you really should be testing directly in BizTalk...